# Ruby on rails 'has many' relation error: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, models

I keep getting this error

> undefined method `concerts' for
>   ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Artist:0xb50b691c>

When trying to do this:

```
<% @artists = Artist.where(name: "Test") %> 

<% @concertTest = @artists.concerts %> #this line raises the error
```

Here are my models:

```
class Concert < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates_presence_of :venue
    validates_presence_of :date

    has_many :reviews
    belongs_to :artist
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates_presence_of :name
    has_many :concerts

end
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this error, and why I can't reference the concerts of a particular artist this way. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this:

```
<% @artists = Artist.where(name: "Test").first %> 

<% @concertTest = @artists.concerts %>
```

Note:- `where` will return `Active record relation` array.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I do .find_by_name instead of .where

```
<% @artists = Artist.find_by_name("Test") %>
<% @concertTest = @artists.concerts %>
```

I'm unsure for the reason of this but maybe someone can comment to clarify it.